# Can't seem to get TFS Permissions correct

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I can't seem to figure out this permission issue. I setup permissions on a TFS collection to allow access to certain folders in that collection. That is working fine. The users are part of a windows group. The users have VS2010 and VS2012, looking under "Team"->"Connect to Team Foundation Server" the users don't see the collection. If I go to Source Control Explorer they can see the collection and are able to use it as they need.

The question is: why can't they see the collection in "Connect to Team Foundation Server"? Is there some special permission that I need to enable to see the collection in "Connect to Team Foundation Server"?

Comment: That's odd. How are you connecting to the collection to see source when they cant connect to the collection?

Comment: When they can't see it I connect to something else on that server that they can see. Once connected I can set the up in source control explorer in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For folks to be able to connect to a Team Project they needs to be in the Reader group of that team project as a minimum. If you just add them to the source control folder without adding then to the team project you will get the symptoms that you report.

If you connect to Team Web Access and navigate to the project you can add the user to the Team on the team dashboard.

If you are using pre-TFS 2012 you can connect in Team Explorer and right-click on the Team Explorer node of the Team Project in question and select "Group Membership". Add the users to at lease Reader, but most likely Contributor.